# Check if a class has a method

Tags: c++, templates, boost, metaprogramming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible for C++ template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/possible-for-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)

Do you know of any metaprogramming tricks in C++ that allow me to check whether a class has a specific method. I has been thinking about something like this:

```
template <class T, class Enable = void> 
class A { ... };

// This version of the class will be compiled if T doesn't have my_method
template <class T>
class A<T, typename enable_if<has_method<T, T::my_method> >::type> { ... };

// This version of the class will be compiled if T has my_method
template <class T>
class A<T, typename disable_if<has_method<T, T::my_method> >::type> { ... };
```

One of the options is to define `my_method` in a class that others may inherit and then use `is_base_of`, but is there nother options that don't require inheritance?

Comment: You are right. I ran a search but didn't find it :( Sorry. Should I close or delete?

Comment: Check this excerpt from Herb Sutter's More Exceptional C++ http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mxc++-item-4.htm